# spark repartition fall into single partition

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am learning spark, and when I tested repartition() function in pyspark shell with the following expression, I observed a very strange result: all elements fall into the same partition after `repartition()` function.
Here, I used `glom()` to learn about the partitioning within the rdd. I was expecting `repartition()` to shuffle the elements and randomly distribute them among partitions. This only happens when I repartition with new number of partitions <= original partitions.

During my test, if I set new number of partitions > original partitions, there is also no shuffling observed. Am I doing anything wrong here?

```
In [1]: sc.parallelize(range(20), 8).glom().collect()
Out[1]:
[[0, 1],
 [2, 3],
 [4, 5],
 [6, 7, 8, 9],
 [10, 11],
 [12, 13],
 [14, 15],
 [16, 17, 18, 19]]

In [2]: sc.parallelize(range(20), 8).repartition(8).glom().collect()
Out[2]:
[[],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 [2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 0, 1, 12, 13, 4, 5, 10, 11],
 []]

In [3]: sc.parallelize(range(20), 8).repartition(10).glom().collect()
Out[3]:
[[],
 [0, 1],
 [14, 15],
 [10, 11],
 [],
 [6, 7, 8, 9],
 [2, 3],
 [16, 17, 18, 19],
 [12, 13],
 [4, 5]]
```

I am using spark version 2.1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations! You just rediscovered [SPARK-21782](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21782) - *Repartition creates skews when numPartitions is a power of 2*:

> Currently, the algorithm for repartition (shuffle-enabled coalesce) is as follows:
>
> for each initial partition index, generate position as (new Random(index)).nextInt(numPartitions)
>       then, for element number k in initial partition index, put it in the new partition position + k (modulo numPartitions).
>
> So, essentially elements are smeared roughly equally over numPartitions buckets - starting from the one with number position+1.
>
> Note that a new instance of Random is created for every initial partition index, with a fixed seed index, and then discarded. So the position is deterministic for every index for any RDD in the world. Also, nextInt(bound) implementation has a special case when bound is a power of 2, which is basically taking several highest bits from the initial seed, with only a minimal scrambling.

PySpark makes it worse, because it [uses batched serializer](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b2ce17b4c9fea58140a57ca1846b2689b15c0d61/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L2102) with default batch size equal to 10 so with small number of items on each partition, all are shuffled to the same output.

Good news is, it is [already resolved in Spark 2.3](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/77d046ec47a9bfa6323aa014869844c28e18e049) thanks to [Sergey Serebryakov](https://github.com/megaserg).

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think there is something to do with the underlying partitioner. I tried with much bigger number and now the result makes more sense.

```
In [95]: [len(lst) for lst in sc.parallelize(range(1000), 8).glom().collect()]
Out[95]: [125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125, 125]

In [96]: [len(lst) for lst in sc.parallelize(range(1000), 8).repartition(10).glom().collect()]
Out[96]: [95, 95, 100, 105, 95, 95, 100, 105, 105, 105]

In [97]: [len(lst) for lst in sc.parallelize(range(1000), 8).repartition(5).glom().collect()]
Out[97]: [190, 195, 205, 210, 200]
```